# Image uploaded with Active storage not showing in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to upgrade and a Rails app to RoR6 with [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html). 
In the view, I use an `image_tag` on the attached image called "whiteboard_background" on `@project`.

And it shows a broken link in the browser:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB8jZ.png)

Environment: development and files stored locally

Model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :whiteboard_background
```

View code:

```
attachment: <%= @project.whiteboard_background.attached? %>
<p>image:
<%= image_tag @project.whiteboard_background if @project.whiteboard_background.attached? %>
</p>
```

Server:

```
Started GET "/projects/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-19 20:29:27 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
...
ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 6], ["record_type", "Project"], ["name", "whiteboard_background"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/projects/show.html.erb:94
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/projects/show.html.erb:96
  Location Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ....
```

I have checked that `@project.whiteboard_background.attached?` is `true` and in the console `Project.last.whiteboard_background.metadata` gives correct image data which indicates that the upload works fine.

The Firefox inspector does show the element with a source path, but says "could not load image". Same behaviour in chrome

If I repeat the process in a blank test app from scratch, it works fine and i can display the image.

Any idea?

Comment: could you post logs from server while loading view with this image?

Comment: server log related to Active Storage added

Answer (score 7):

The error was due to the following "catch all" at the end of my rails routes:
`get "*path", to: redirect('/')`

It seems the browser is not able to load the image with the URL given by active storage due to forced redirection to root. This was not an issue using previous upload method (carrierwave)

Removing this line from routes.rb fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For images on local storage use this

```
<%= url_for(@project.whiteboard_background) %>
```

It if is in production and on something like S3 then you probably want something like this

```
<%= @project.whiteboard_background.service_url %>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but that didnt solve it.
The firefox inspector does show the element with a source path, but says  "could not load image".
Same behavior in chrome.

Comment: so where are the files being stored, s3, or somewhere else, sounds like there may be a permission issue with the files perhaps?

Comment: files are stored locally with default settings. i also tried with several images of different types, they appear fine in my other test app where i just tried to reproduce the process...

Comment: Ok can you verify the images are in fact being loaded into the folder that is being linked to in the URL you see in the inspector?  I think it usually goes to `/storage/../..`so on.  Are those images actually there?

Comment: do you mean in the browser cache?
Tracing the image in Firefox cache entries with the URL from the inspector, I can indeed find a record with the right URL, but it has 0kb! 
so that s consistent with the "could not load image" error in the inspector

Comment: No, I mean in your app, the files have to be going somwhere and that is where active storage sends them.  I would like like this `/storage/el/vb/lksdfj9348rfohenfsoighwoefhwdsodfj`  Something odd like that

Comment: ah, well it was related to a "catch all" i had in my routes as last line: 
get "*path", to: redirect('/').

After comnenting this to try out what you proposed, the image loaded fine and I can also reach it directly with the source URL. 

So it seems this "catch all" route conflicts with the way active storage works. 
Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: service_url works for me in production, but throws an error in dev environment. I added this to the controller of the object to which the images are attached: before_action: set_host for local storage ....  private def set_host_for_local_storage
        ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url if Rails.application.config.active_storage.service == :local
    end ... and now servie_url works in both dev and production

Answer (score 0):

The upload might not be done. The upload is done by an `after_commit` callback in `activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/model.rb`.

You can check in your code if you have an other callback that might conflicts with this one.

If the cause is different, you can start there to investigate and debug any upload issue.